# PowerBI - SSAS Multidimensional Performance

Tags: ssas, powerbi

I have a multidimensional molap cube with 15 measures and ~15  dimensions. 
The cube is browsed from POWER BI service, and the SSAS server use an "on premises data gateway" with the memory of 24GB.
When I browse a table visualization report with value contains of 1 measure and 3 attributes from different dimensions, the result seems good that I can have the report appeared.
But when I try to add more (another) attributes, the report just keep loading (loading forever) and the memory in the ssas server is used until exhausted.
Please advise what should I do when I face that issue?

Note : 
I have tried to browse the SSAS with the same measures and dimensions in SSMS the report is appeared. 
I saw 2 DAX query from power bi when I did profiling on SSAS. The first query got error “The operation has been cancelled because there is not enough memory available for the application..”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have too many calculated measures in SSAS, move some of them to the views as the calculated measures are high cpu and memory usage.